# The request was aborted: The request was canceled. C# with Cloudinary upload

Tags: c#, request, timeout, config, cloudinary

I am having an issue with uploading a file larger than 4 megs to cloudinary, 
I am using C# to upload the file. 
I have set up my app under configs to allow for a larger number for uploads as follows:

```
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" />
```

and

```
<security>
<requestFiltering>
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
</requestFiltering>
</security>
```

My section of code doing this is as follows:

```
Stream trackStream = trackfile.InputStream;
var uploadParams = new RawUploadParams
{
File = new FileDescription(trackName, trackStream),
Folder = "tracks"
};

RawUploadResult uploadResult = _cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);

return uploadResult.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

however there is an arror when i try to send the file:
The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
and the exception is thrown on this action:

```
RawUploadResult uploadResult = _cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
```

[image]

Comment: How is your configuration related to Cloudinary? As I understand that is third party service and it has nothing to do with your configuration files. Maybe you just hitting some image size limit according to your Clourinary plan?

Comment: I was assuming that my app is failing to keep up the channel/stream between itself the cloudinary service, as far as i have seen there isn't a restriction dependent on the plan i am using with cloudinary. And the file is surely being pulled into the http request just the transfer this happens.